# Is the same working principle of a vacuum ejector (fluid eductor, pressure ejector or "motive flow") viable to be used as a propulsion system?

Tags: aircraft-physics, propulsion, fluid-mechanics

Some time ago [I've made a question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90786/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fluidic-thrust-vectoring-on-aircraf) involving Jetoptera bladeless propulsion, and got a comment saying they didn't know how that method of propulsion would make any difference. But I forgot to ask more specifically about said propulsion system.

---

So, the principle which is normally used in [vacuum ejectors or aspirators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_ejector) is normally used to [inflate the evacuation slide of an airplane](https://youtu.be/24XbGuKrvuU), as [fuel injectors](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34301/what-is-motive-flow-and-why-is-it-used-in-some-aircraft-hydraulic-systems), [liquid mixers](https://youtu.be/iGFpF7HtZdA) and myriad of other things.

[image: Illustration explaining how the motive flow works.]

The thing is that the Jetoptera's aircraft claims to use this same motive flow to produce thrust, and like any other company with a "revolutionary idea", it claims it is more efficient at producing thrust than other types of propulsion systems.

[image: Illustration showing how the Jetoptera aircraft propulsion works]
More information about how Jetoptera is (supposed to work) in [this video](https://youtu.be/bPZI6XoHi10) and in [this video](https://youtu.be/buflSdO-MDY), in the [original channel of Jetoptera](https://www.youtube.com/@jetoptera3749/videos) it only show tunnel testings and gliders with two hollow boxes that you can't even tell if they're actually working.

---

### The question:

Ignoring the claims of efficiency (maybe even the Jetoptera's case itself) and so on: would the motive flow be any good as a propulsion system by itself?

Comment: Another duplicate of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53771/21091)

Comment: I'm told that Dyson fans look cool but they actually suck as fans.